# ubuntu-14.04 - why can I only connect only on one ethernet interface

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ethernet

I have multiple interfaces on a server, but I can only connect on one of them, I cannot ping the other one, I don't understand why. IP addresses are given by a dhcp server, the interfaces receive them. The only reachable is `p10p1`.

`bond0` receives the correct IP, but is unreachable, and unusable, as I try `ping -I bond0 whatever` and nothing gets returned.

Any suggestions? I am lost.

Here's the ifconfig output:

```
bond0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3e:6d:0e:b0:27:f9
      inet addr:10.194.121.34  Bcast:10.194.121.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::3c6d:eff:feb0:27f9/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:21 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:5663 (5.6 KB)

em1   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3e:6d:0e:b0:27:f9
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:2510 (2.5 KB)
      Memory:fb320000-fb340000

em2   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3e:6d:0e:b0:27:f9
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:13 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:3153 (3.1 KB)
      Memory:fb300000-fb320000

ham0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7a:79:19:33:bc:e7
      inet addr:25.51.188.231  Bcast:25.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: 2620:9b::1933:bce7/96 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fe80::7879:19ff:fe33:bce7/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1404  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:110 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:23639 (23.6 KB)

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:114 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:114 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:18316 (18.3 KB)  TX bytes:18316 (18.3 KB)

p10p1 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:36:9f:c0:b9:20
      inet addr:10.194.121.35  Bcast:10.194.121.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fd69:620:600:121:a236:9fff:fec0:b920/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fdf9:620:600:121:a236:9fff:fec0:b920/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fe80::a236:9fff:fec0:b920/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:20177 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1281 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:1433816 (1.4 MB)  TX bytes:158707 (158.7 KB)
```

The content of `/etc/network/interfaces` is

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto em1
iface em1 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto em2
iface em2 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet dhcp
hwaddress 3e:6d:0e:b0:27:f9
bond-mode 4
bond-miion 100
bond-lacp-rate 1
bond-slave em1 em2

auto p10p1
iface p10p1 inet dhcp
```

iptables rules:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports mdns
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports 4000

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**EDIT**

Here's some of the `tcpdump` output:

```
listening on bond0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
16:31:51.519853 LACPv1, length 110
16:31:53.094920 LACPv1, length 110
16:31:58.571537 DTPv1, length 38
16:31:58.571605 78:ba:f9:d4:04:b1 (oui Unknown) > 01:00:0c:00:00:00 (oui Unknown) SNAP, oui Cisco (0x00000c), pid Unknown (0x0003), length 68:
    0x0000:  aaaa 0300 000c 0003 0000 0000 0100 0ccc  ................
    0x0010:  cccc 78ba f9d4 04b1 0027 aaaa 0300 000c  ..x......'......
    0x0040:  b100 1c00 0000 0100 72bb 416e            ........r.An
16:31:59.628587 DTPv1, length 38
16:31:59.628623 54:a2:74:2e:0c:71 (oui Unknown) > 01:00:0c:00:00:00 (oui Unknown) SNAP, oui Cisco (0x00000c), pid Unknown (0x0003), length 68:
    0x0000:  aaaa 0300 000c 0003 0000 0000 0100 0ccc  ................
    0x0010:  cccc 54a2 742e 0c71 0027 aaaa 0300 000c  ..T.t..q.'......
    0x0040:  7102 000f 0000 0000 594b c650            q.......YK.P
^C
6 packets captured
6 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Comment: Do you try to ping something in the same subnet or in a remote subnet? Also: have you had at the packages leaving from and arriving on bond0 with tcpdump?

Comment: I would know how to do that :-(

Comment: When you run `tcpdump -n -vv -i bond0` it shows you all incoming and outgoing packets on interface bond0.

Comment: You use LACP protocol for bonding, but Cisco switches can't usually do it. Also show the output of command `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`.

Comment: What address are you trying to ping? Try to listen on p10p1 - may be replies are going in from other side? Or, maybe you bonding setup is incorrect. To check this, try `arping -I bond0 10.194.121.1` (change this to an existing address)

Comment: And what are you trying to do? This setup (two interfaces in one ip network) will not work correctly without some magic (policy routing)

Comment: @WhiteWind, I would like to be able to access the server using two different IP address, I thought that would be possible. That is true that bond0 stopped working after I've setup the p10p1 interface!

Comment: Thank you all for the time spent for me. I understand now that what I was trying to achieve is not something to do, my bad